# Using DbConnection as property with only get or as method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a disposable class which includes DB connection and memory cache client.

My class will have some data. First, it will look at cache for data. If the cache is empty then it will get data from DB and cache the data.

I don't want to open a DB connection until it is not required. However, I am not sure that if I put DB connection as a property, it will not open connection until I call it.

I show two options in the code example below. Let me know which one would be better and why?

```
public class ViewContentModel : IDisposable
{
    #region get alternative
    public virtual IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory
    {
        get { return HostContext.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>(); }
    }
    private IDbConnection db;
    public virtual IDbConnection Db
    {
        get { return db ?? (db = DbFactory.OpenDbConnection()); }
    }
    #endregion
    #region method alternative

    private IDbConnection db;
    public virtual IDbConnection Db()
    {
        if (db != null)
            return db;
        var DbFactory = HostContext.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>();
        return db = DbFactory.OpenDbConnection();
    }
    #endregion



    private ICacheClient cache;
    public virtual ICacheClient Cache
    {
        get { return cache ?? (cache = HostContext.TryResolve<ICacheClient>()); }
    }
    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (db != null)
            db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a cache is an incorrect approach as it prevents proper disposal. Your database connections are pooled so the cache is unnecessary.

Comment: I don't want to dispose the data. Just want to dispose model.